# Clone Windows (11) to new SSD and dual-boot from new and old

Tags: multi-boot, dualboot, bcd, bcdedit

I have added a secondary SSD to my laptop and cloned the disk with Clonezilla.
I call them SSD1 and SSD2.
Now I have two identical disks with Windows 11. But I'm not able to boot from the new secondary SSD.

In Bios I have UEFI activated. And it points to the Windows Boot Manager (most probably on the first SSD1). From the SSD1 I have run bcdedit.exe and copied the Windows Boot Loader so my SSD1 contains two Windows Boot Loaders in the UEFI partition. I get the option to start the secondary Windows option, but after a while, I just got a black screen and no messages.

I also tried with EasyBCD and created the new entry but with the same result.

```
C:\Windows\System32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {95d66f77-7eaf-11ed-99e4-9cd32abd1438}
displayorder            {current}
                        {c5abcfc5-ef11-11ed-87ac-00a554b6b899}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {95d66f79-7eaf-11ed-99e4-9cd32abd1438}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {95d66f77-7eaf-11ed-99e4-9cd32abd1438}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {c5abcfc5-ef11-11ed-87ac-00a554b6b899}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume12
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Microsoft Windows
locale                  en-US
osdevice                partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume12
systemroot              \Windows
```

Another approach could be to actually select the SSD1 or SSD2 to boot from, instead of the Windows Boot Manager (located at SSD1). But in that case, I need to modify "something", because I guess the Boot Manager and Boot Loader on SSD2 have references to `\Device\HarddiskVolume1`.

Also, If I decide to install the two systems from scratch I have the option to have only one disk present at the time of installation, then they will be completely isolated with different Boot Managers, but I don't know if I will go that path.

Comment: EasyBCD doesn't work for UEFI.

Comment: Is it true for Windows as well? I thought it was for non-windows.

I did also copied the current with bcdedit.exe and got the same end-result (black screen), but slightly different parameters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries): `bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Microsoft Windows"`

Comment: EasyBCD is Windows software so necessarily for Windows and Windows only. There's EasyUEFI for modern computers (~2012 or newer). If you reinstall you won't need to worry about bootloaders, the 2nd Windows instance will detect the 1st and add itself to the original bootloader, that's how Windows works.

Comment: Ok, there are some commercial tools, but shouldn't bcdedit.exe be able to make it?

Comment: Don't know. I use Linux 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Must be ok to do in Windows with bcdedit.exe for a dual boot Windows installation. :) I just need to figure out how to set the parameters correctly.